# Align text right Html Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, text-align, right-align

I'm trying to align text in Html but it doesn't work and I do not know why. I'm using Ionic Framework.

My code is:

```
<ion-list>
   <ion-item>
      <b>Name</b> <p align="right"> {{paciente.name}}</p>
   </ion-item>
   ....
</ion-list>
```

and it looks like this:
[image]

but I want all text int the same line, and I do not know how to get that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a css class as

```
.item {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

See this demo: http://play.ionic.io/app/b477ea2f5623
In ionic items, if you write any text within `span` with `item-note` class then it will be aligned to right.This is built in class by ionic, your code will be like this :

```
<ion-item>
  <b>Name</b> <span class="item-note"> {{paciente.name}}</span>
</ion-item>
```

See more tricks with ionic items provide by built in classes, see this [Documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-icons)

Answer (score 2):

The p tag creates a paragraph on a new line, so you need an other element. You could use a span element which is floated right:

Html:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
  <b>Name</b> <span class="right"> {{paciente.name}}</span>
</ion-item>
....
</ion-list>
```

Css:

```
.right {
  float: right;
}
```

Apply the ckass to all items you want to be on the right.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for asking so fast, but it looks like my image too.